# Cursor not appearing in Unity with Screen.lockCursor = false;

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

**Unity version: 2017.2.0b11**

In my game when the Inventory Panel is visible on the screen, the cursor should appear so that i can click and interact. I always have to press esc key to make the cursor visible and even from that the cursor disappears after clicking.

Below is my javascript script

```
var OurInventory : GameObject;
var InvStatus : int;

function Update(){
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Inventory")){
        if (InvStatus == 0){
            Screen.lockCursor = false;
            InvStatus = 1;
            OurInventory.SetActive(true);
        }
        else {
            Screen.lockCursor = true;
            OurInventory.SetActive(false);
            InvStatus = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my C# script

```
﻿using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Shop01Access : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject ShopInventory;
    public GameObject Item01Text;
    public GameObject Item02Text;
    public GameObject Item03Text;
    public GameObject Item04Text;
    public GameObject ItemCompletion;
    public GameObject CompleteText;
    
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        ShopInventory.SetActive(true);
        Screen.lockCursor = false;
        GlobalShop.ShopNumber = 1;
        Item01Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GlobalShop.Item01;
        Item02Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GlobalShop.Item02;
        Item03Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GlobalShop.Item03;
        Item04Text.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GlobalShop.Item04;
    }
    
    public void Item01() {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy " + GlobalShop.Item01 + "?";
    }
    
    public void Item02() {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy " + GlobalShop.Item02 + "?";
    }
    
    public void Item03() {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy " + GlobalShop.Item03 + "?";
    }
    
    public void Item04() {
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(true);
        CompleteText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Are you sure you want to buy " + GlobalShop.Item04 + "?";
    }
    
    public void CancelTransaction(){
        ItemCompletion.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `Cursor.lockState`  instead by doing `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked` or in your case `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None` in your OnTriggerEnter. Let me know if that works. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html

Comment: I have used Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None and still got no results. I have tried this in both the scripts above. Can it be that i am running the Unity Editor(Linux version) in Linux therefore not able to get the cursor unlock.

Comment: The cursor is just visible for 1 sec and then vanishes. Used below in place of Screen.lockCursor:-

Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
Cursor.visible = true;